# Visual Studio 2015 Asp.net 5 application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a new Asp.net 5 project following [this page](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html):

Just after creating the project I have this error message:

> the specified default content type (default) is not defined in the project item schema

And the project elements mentioned in the page are not available.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Sounds like something messed up with your installation, I would try re-installing Visual Studio 2015 and then also install the latest beta7 web tooling if you haven't already. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_devresources

Comment: I reinstalled everything but I still have the same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I re-installed Visual Studio (in french) as Joe Audette advised but this didn't solve the problem. Once again, I re-installed it, but this time in english: problem solved.